# Button/Div appearing outside box when floating it right

Tags: html, css

I have created a box and I'm trying to float the button on the right side of the box. When I do that the button appears half below the box. How can I fix this?

Here's the [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/57sect09/2/)

This is what my CSS looks like

```css
.rightColumn {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}
.button {
  float: right;
}
```

It should look something like

```
 Title
 Summary
             |Find out more|
```

Comment: Remove the `<br>` tag above the `<button>` tag. - http://jsfiddle.net/57sect09/3/

Comment: But I want the button to be on the next line. Is that possible?

Comment: Try this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ecztsxje/

Comment: But the margins are gone. I just want it to appear in the next line    .

Comment: I think, it's on the next line in my above updated fiddle, try this demo [edited] - http://jsfiddle.net/Lgae8svf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the problem but I know how to fix it. When you float something in some non-floated element things go wrong. You have to float the parent or add `clearfix` CSS to it. Here is my [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/57sect09/7/)
and here is `clearfix` class CSS:

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove "br" tag after summary. But remember If summary content will be larger, button will be floated down, to avoid this fix width for summary content. 
If you want button in new line, set your box height as your requirement. Currently box height is default.

Answer (score 0):

add position absolute

```css
.button {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
}
```

and put the "button" tag after the "img" tag

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x100">
<button class="button"><a href="#">Find out more</a></button>
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/57sect09/5/

Comment: position absolute is the last thing anyone wants to deal with in css, if you ever find yourself using this believe me you are doing something easy in a wrong way.

Comment: But i think he is newbie. i know better way for css :)) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change `</button>` with `</button>&nbsp;`. Floats objects like to have something behind.